# Debugger issues with Visual Studio and WP7 emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a complex C# project that I ported over from C++ and now I'm in the middle of debugging. Things are working great most of the time but more often than not I have huge problems with Visual Studio and debugger attached to WP7 emulator. For some strange reasons, my debug session is often abruptly terminated while stepping through the code without any indication from VS or any trace left in the Output window.

There are even some cases when a breakpoint is hit and then when I hover over a particular variable, VS simply exits the current debugging session. If I refrain from inspecting the variable contents, nothing happens and VS waits happily forever.

As the app is a memory hog by definition, I am wondering whether I am hitting any debugger / WP7 / emulator limits of any kind. Why would a mouse over variable terminate debugging session? Most of all, why is there no trace of what happened? I am left to wonder whether this is a VS issue or an emulator issue or even an app issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/f9b08dd4-8d20-4104-9a24-9f002caceb48?prof=required) which has helped me immensely. It appears that having `ToString()` overrides can sometimes crash the debugging session. I have implemented mine for the sole purpose of having customized value representation of variables/values in the debugger.

After removing all the `ToString()` overrides I am able to debug normally again. The thing that still puzzles me is the fact that no exceptions are leaked from my `ToString()` overrides so I wonder why debugger behaves the way it does but at least the problem is solved for now.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

What are your computer specs?

I have seen similar problems on computers with low specs, especially computers with low memory.

Try clearing out memory hogs from your PC (CCleaner is a good tool) and running Visual Studio in administrator mode.

Comment: I am running a PC with Intel 8-core i7 2GHz CPU and 8GB RAM. That should really be sufficient, shouldn't it?

Comment: Running VS with elevated privileges makes no difference.

Comment: Haha - yes it absolutely should be fine. Strange behaviour, however I see you have answered your own query above. :)